# How can i send data from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Well i need to send my array from javascript to php.

My array structure

```
body[circle.id] = [currentid-1,event.offsetX,event.offsetY];
```

My javascript code.

```
for(let i = 0;i < body.length;i++){
$.ajax({                    
  url: 'get.php',     
  type: 'post', 
  data : {
    id : body[0,i],
    x : body[1,i],
    y : body[2,i]
  },
  dataType: 'json',                   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not the correct way to index a 2-dimensional array. It should be:

```
  data : {
    id : body[i][0],
    x : body[i][1],
    y : body[i][2]
  },
```

You could also make the elements of `body` be objects instead of arrays, then you can just pass that directly:

```
body[circle.id] = {id: currentid-1, x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY]};
```

Then you would do:

```
data: body[i],
```

Comment: Thank you, It works, but i don't even know how to get this data in php i'm new to programing..

Comment: In PHP it will be `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['x']` and `$_POST['y']`. Just like normal form inputs.

Comment: That looks like a server configuration problem, it's blocking POST requests for some reason.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The error has nothing to do with that.

Comment: The problem is in your Apache configuration.

Comment: Can you help me with this or you dont know?

Comment: I don't know Apache configuration, sorry.